# XeLaTex + FontAwesome

Tags: fonts, latex, font-awesome

I am trying to use FontAwesome in XeLaTex on OS X.
So I followed the steps described on this [github](https://gist.github.com/sway/3101743):

1. Save this into your project folder as fontawesome.sty
2. Put \usepackage{fontawesome} into the preamble
3. Define command for FontAwesome: \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome Regular}
4. Redefine required characters (optional): \def\twitter{{\FA \faTwitter}}
5. Use: \href{http://twitter.com/swaycz}{\twitter\ swaycz}

So that the beginning of my .tex file look like this:

```
\documentclass{.......}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome Regular}
\begin{document}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `FontAwesome Regular', contains ' '
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `FontAwesome Regular', contains ' '

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FontAwesome Regular" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

It seems like it is not finding the font. 
After some research, I tried loading the font with:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{
    Path = /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/ }
\usepackage{fontawesome}
```

instead of *\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome Regular}* but it was not working either.

I am still new with LaTex and I do appreciate your time, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fontspec taps into your system fonts by default, so: FontAwesome needs to be installed as a normal system font like every other. If you don't see it in Fontbook or the like, you didn't install it properly.

(lines 7 and 8 of the gist you quote mention this, but I'm reiterating it just in case)

If instead you want to run it "from file" rather than installing it as system font, don't use `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome Regular}` but use the "from path" way to load a font file, as explained over on the tex.stackexchange site, in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/load-fonts-that-are-in-a-fonts-directory

Answer (score 5):

Once download the font file from FontAwesome and install to be system font, open the font application and confirm the FontAwesome name.

Due to FontAwesome version is 5.7.2 at this time, this version has three font type in system font.

Their names are

> Font Awesome 5 Free Regular
>
> Font Awesome 5 Free Solid
>
> Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular

So define command for FontAwesome:

```
\newfontfamily{\FAFR}{Font Awesome 5 Free Regular}
\newfontfamily{\FAFS}{Font Awesome 5 Free Solid}
\newfontfamily{\FAB}{Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular}
```

Simply redefine:

```
\def\faEmail{{\FAFR \symbol{"F0E0}}} % Email
\def\faPhone{\FAFS \symbol{"F095}} % Phone
\def\faLinkedin{\FAB \symbol{"F08C}} % Linkedin
\def\faGithub{\FAB \symbol{"F09B}} % Github
\def\faStackOverflow{\FAB \symbol{"F16C}} % StackOverflow
```

Comment: First of all: thank you for this answer as it was very useful. A small problem I ran into while just copying the redefinitions - it is important to use two brackets before \FA* because if you do not the section is not restricted to just this character but the whole part. \def\faEmail{{\FAFR \symbol{"F0E0}}} % Email <- correct, \def\faPhone{\FAFS \symbol{"F095}} % Phone <- incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlpVKUpraao) particularly useful. Please do the following.

1. Follow the instruction given by the video (putting FontAwesome.otf into OSX Font Book application)
2. Put \usepackage{fontawesome} into the XeLaTeX preamble
3. Define command for FontAwesome: \newfontfamily{\FA}{**FontAwesome**} (**Note:** FontAwesome instead of FontAwesome Regular works for me)
4. Redefine required characters (optional): \def\mytweet{{\FA\symbol{"**F099**}}}
   . You can find more symbols here (http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/). (**Note:** All letters are in capital, f099 won't work)
5. Use: \href{http://twitter.com/}{\mytweet} as a clickable tweet icon

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem! After hours struggling, I solved by using `fontawesome5` instead, there are small changes with icon names following by this link: https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf